# efficient rails query includes record (returns boolean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

My people have scores and I'd like an efficient way to query if the given user is in the top X users.

```
# person.rb
class Person
  scope :top_score, -> {order('score DESC')}
  scope :page_limit, -> { limit(10) }

  def self.in_top_score(id)
    top_score.page_limit.something_something_soemthign?
  end
end
```

**previously was doing:**

```
user.id.in?(top_score.page_limit.pluck(:id))
```

but i'd prefer to move this check to the database to prevent the object serialization of hundreds/thousands of records.

```
Person.order('score DESC').select([:score, :id]).limit(1)
Person Load (0.5ms)  SELECT score, id FROM `people` ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
=> [#<Person id: "dxvrDy...", score: 35>]
```

#### now to check if another user exists in that list^^

```
Person.order('score DESC').select([:score, :id]).limit(1).exists?({id: "c_Tvr6..."})
Person Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `people` WHERE `people`.`id` = 'c_Tvr6...' LIMIT 1 
=> true
```

returns true but should return false

Comment: basically i want to do `Person.actually_exists?({})` instead of `Person.where({}).pluck(:id).include?(id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### updated answer

Sorry, my original answer was incorrect. (The `exists?` query evidently uses `LIMIT 1` and overwrites the `LIMIT 10` from the `page_limit` scope, and evidently throws out the `ORDER BY` clause, too. Totally wrong! :-p)

What about this? It's a little bit less elegant, but I actually tested the answer this time :-p, and it seems to work as desired.

```
def self.in_top_score?(id)
  where(id: id).where(id: Person.top_score.page_limit).exists?
end
```

Here's an example usage from my testing (using Rails 4.2.6) and the SQL it generates (which uses a subquery):

```
pry(main)> Person.in_top_score?(56)
  Person Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 AND "people"."id" IN (SELECT  "people"."id" FROM "people"  ORDER BY "people"."score" DESC LIMIT 10) LIMIT 1  [["id", 56]]
=> false
```

In my testing, this does indeed have at least a bit of a performance boost compared to your original version.

---

#### original answer

```
top_score.page_limit.exists?(user.id)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F

Comment: i just tested this and the sql/result is not correct(at least in rails 3) i'll update the question

Comment: you're right! my bad, @BlairAnderson. I updated my answer.